# Thunderbird - how to minimize local storage

Tags: email, imap, thunderbird

I work in an office where I occasionally need to check the main office email. However, I don't want or need any email from the account other than when I check it manually.

At the moment I have hundreds of email (probably only headers?) in the thunderbird account. I would like to know how to 'clean' this account in Thunderbird without deleting or messing with any mail on the IMAP server.

Can you tell me what I can do. I've searched and searched on the web but cannot find instructions for my particular problem. Thanks

Comment: IMAP is by design meant to show you all messages available on the server, however if you follow the instructions in the answer below you will be only downloading headers except for messages you open. The alternative to display only recent emails would be using POP3, and configuring *every* client to leave messages on the server for X days (configurable). If you're the only POP3 client you will still download all messages since last time you accessed it (there may be a setting to limit this).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that by keeping the local copies limited (either by age or by size), go to **Account Settings**, **"Synchronization & storage"**, **"Disk Space**.

From here, you can configure the **FIRST SYNCHRONIZATION OPTION** (Important! If you mess with the lower options you might delete copies on the mail server). Photo is attached for reference:
[image: Reference]

Note: On the next restart, you can see that only the mails within a specific timeframe is saved on the device. Alternatively, you can manually delete old messages locally in %AppData%\Thunderbird\

Hope this helps!